# Autocomplete of primefaces not working with update version of primefaces jar .only with primefaces 2.0

Tags: primefaces

My autocomplete tag is usable only with older version of primefaces 2.0
other than that if i add any jar with greater version it gives error on completeMethod attribute that it cannot find property (method i am using in completeMethod).
I need to use upgraded version of primefaces as i need other newer tags of primefaces.
Kindly give some help in this regard.

Thanks

**EDITED:**
here is the code :

```
   <tr> <td>Current Education Level</td>                            
                                    <td> 
                                        <h:panelGrid styleClass="text-box">
                                             <p:autoComplete id="education" value="#{input.education}" completeMethod="#{input.getautocomplete}" var="a" itemLabel="#{a.Name}" itemValue="#{a}"  converter="edConverter" forceSelection="true"/>  

                                            <p:column>  
                                                #{a.Name} - #{a.id}  
                                            </p:column>    
                                        </h:panelGrid>
                                    </td>                                                          
                             </tr>
```

this autocomplete works fine and gives results when using primefaces 2.0 but if jar is replaced by a newer version or version 3.4 it gives following error:
       **javax.el.ELException: /WebPages/SearchPages/Search.xhtml: 
       The class  'com.Bean.Service' does not have the property 'getautocomplete'.**

the jars i put is in lib folder of WEBINF and using glassfish server 3.1.2. Namespace i add when using primefaces 2.0 is **xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"**
and when using version 3.4 i replace it with **xmlns:p=http://primefaces.org/ui**

i dont know what can be the problem ,can it be problem with eclipse or Mojarra 2.1.6???

Comment: this does not make any sense. completeMethod exists in also primefaces versions. take a look at the showcase, for current version (3.4). starting on version 3.0 of primefaces, the namespace changed. are you using the right one? (xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui")

Comment: i used the mentioned namespace its still giving error

Comment: **javax.el.ELException: /WebPages/SearchPages/Search.xhtml: The class 'com.Bean.Service' does not have the property 'getautocompleteName'.** is the error..it is considering the completeMethod as El expression not method

Comment: Also i am using JSF version 2.0 in my application

Comment: please show relevants part of your code (xhtml and managed bean), otherwise it will be hard to help you

Comment: kindly recheck the question edited

Comment: Have you tried to rename `getautocomplete` to somehting without a `get`? Maybe `doAutocomplete`?. 
I do not really know how the handling of attributes in EL works and how attributes are seperated from method calls. But for attributes you leave out `get` and `set` and still your getter and setter for that attribute are called. So when using a method I would just not name those methods starting with get nor set. 
Worth a try.

Comment: sorry for late reply. I changed the method name also to autoComplete from getautocomplete.still not working

Comment: I also migrated vom 2.2.1 to 3.4. Your hint about changing the namespace to xmlns:p=http://primefaces.org/ui for 3.4 saved me :-) Thanks.